# EF Core: The entity type 'List<Course>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to update columns in the database for a `Courses` table, but get the following error:

> The entity type 'List' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

Basically I'm trying to get the state of the check boxes. For example if a course is selected for an Instructor as an author of that course, then enter the instructor's Id into the `Course.AuthorId`

Here is the method in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditInstructorCourse(int id, List<EditInstructorCourseViewModel> model)
{
        if (_context.Courses is null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var courses = await _context.Courses.ToListAsync();

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
            {
                if (model[i].IsAuthor = true)
                {
                    courses[i].AuthorId = id;
                    _context.Update(courses);
                }
                else
                {
                    courses[i].AuthorId = null;
                }
            }

            _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Here is the view model

```
public class EditInstructorCourseViewModel
{
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseAuthor { get; set; }
    public string CourseEditor { get; set; }

    public bool IsAuthor { get; set; }
    public bool IsEditor { get; set; }
}
```

The model classes:

```
public class Instructor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Instructor")]
    public string InstructorName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    [DisplayName("Author Of")]
    public ICollection<Course> CoursesAuthored { get; set; } = new List<Course>();

    [ForeignKey("EditorId")]
    [DisplayName("Editor Of")]
    public List<Course> CoursesEdited { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Course")]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Instructor? Author { get; set; }
    public int? EditorId { get; set; }
    public Instructor? Editor { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
        .HasOne(course => course.Editor)
        .WithMany(editor => editor.CoursesEdited)
        .HasForeignKey(course => course.EditorId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
        .HasOne(course => course.Author)
        .WithMany(editor => editor.CoursesAuthored)
        .HasForeignKey(course => course.AuthorId);
}
```

And the view

```
@model List<OneToManyMany.Models.ViewModels.EditInstructorCourseViewModel>

@{
    var instructorId = ViewData["InstructorId"];
    var instructorName = ViewData["InstructorName"];
}

<h2>Edit Courses for <strong> @instructorName</strong></h2>


<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@instructorName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="@instructorName" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@instructorName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <form asp-action="EditInstructorCourse" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@instructorId" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Author Of</h5>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="form-check m-1">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].CourseId" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].CourseName" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].IsAuthor" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model[i].IsAuthor">
                        @Model[i].CourseName
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Editor Of</h5>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="form-check m-1">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].CourseId" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].CourseName" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].IsEditor" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model[i].IsEditor">
                        @Model[i].CourseName
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="mt-4">
            <a asp-controller="Instructors" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@instructorId" class="btn btn-secondary me-2">Cancel</a>
            <button id="saveBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The line `_context.Update(courses);` is the problem since you are passing list to `Update` method which expects single entity. The line is redundant anyway, just remove it and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the entity: you need to get the entity, update the value and call SaveChangesAsync. No need to call update in your case. Just remove it as suggested by @ivan